# I can only see the wireframe of my objects and they don´t appear in the render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I was testing with shadow catchers, glowing textures and smoke in a project and now, all of my meshes are in wireframe and don´t show in renders and I would like to reset everything. I would like to start again but preserving the meshes, their location and scale; I don´t care about everything else like materials, visibility settings of the objects or render settings. I thought about appending the meshes into a new proyect,but, besides I´ve tried and I can´t, I think the visibility settings would remain the same. Anyone can help please?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I`ve solved it, I don´t know why but I had this (the box inside the red circle) in "wire".